# Why does cx_Oracle bulk insert fail on Windows but work on Linux?

Tags: python, linux, windows, oracle, cx-oracle

I am using the cx_Oracle executemany() function to insert 500,000 rows into a table in batches of 200,000. The function works on RHEL Linux and fails on Windows 7. The issue persists regardless of user, database, and table. The issue only occurs when inserting more than ~150,000 rows. Please help me understand why this fails on Windows and how to solve the issue.

Python 3.5

cx_Oracle 5.3

Error message is ORA-03114: not connected to ORACLE.

Code is

```
#   Create an Oracle connection
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user= user, password= pwd, dsn = tns)
#   Create a cursor
cursor = cx_Oracle.Cursor(connection)
try:
    #   Compile the insert SQL w/ bind variable        
    cursor.prepare(insert_sql)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    #   Execute the insert statement, commit & close connection
    cursor.executemany(None, row_batch)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
    time.sleep(0.01)  
#   In case of error, still close the connection!
#   This avoids a table lock when accessing the table from a different connection
#   at a later date, if this Python session is still active
except Exception as e:        
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
    raise Exception(e)
```

Comment: check the alert log - my guess is that your session/process memory area is exhausted and the db terminates your session. try decreasing the batch amount to say 25k or 50k - but ALSO check your alert log

Comment: also, do some timing.  Diminishing returns here - typically you'll not see much improvement after 500-1000 rows per batch